# How to use variable in drop table statement mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I want to use variable name in drop table statement in mysql.

```
set @dropable:='table_name';
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS @dropable;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a prepared statement here:

```
SET @droptable := 'table_name';
SET @sql := CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ', @droptable);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```